# install opencv in existing dockerfile in gitlab

Tags: opencv, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHSUB.jpg)**i added below code to my docker file and the job run successfully but , in modules java in not available.**

```
first FROM python:3.9

LABEL mantainer="Baher Elnaggar eng.baher77@gmail.com"

WORKDIR /opt/build

ENV OPENCV_VERSION="4.5.1"

RUN apt-get -qq update
&& apt-get -qq install -y --no-install-recommends
build-essential
cmake
git
wget
unzip
yasm
pkg-config
libswscale-dev
libtbb2
libtbb-dev
libjpeg-dev
libpng-dev
libtiff-dev
libopenjp2-7-dev
libavformat-dev
libpq-dev
&& pip install numpy
&& wget -q https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip -O opencv.zip \

&& unzip -qq opencv.zip -d /opt \
&& rm -rf opencv.zip \
&& cmake \
    -D BUILD_TIFF=ON \
    -D BUILD_opencv_java=OFF \
    -D WITH_CUDA=OFF \
    -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
    -D WITH_OPENCL=ON \
    -D WITH_IPP=ON \
    -D WITH_TBB=ON \
    -D WITH_EIGEN=ON \
    -D WITH_V4L=ON \
    -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
    -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
    -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(python3.9 -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)") \
    -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3.9) \
    -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python3.9 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") \
    -D PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=$(python3.9 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") \
    /opt/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION} \
&& make -j$(nproc) \
&& make install \
&& rm -rf /opt/build/* \
&& rm -rf /opt/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION} \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& apt-get -qq autoremove \
&& apt-get -qq clean
Then i added Java_home

RUN apt-get update &&
apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk &&
apt-get install -y ant &&
apt-get clean &&
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/ &&
rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer;

    enter code here

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/ RUN export JAVA_HOME
```

**But still job run successfully but my requirements is not satisfied . Can any one tell me to install opencv with java_home 8

My requirement is to add opencv layer to my docker image . i need to install OPENCV , i am added this code in my existing dockerfile in gitlab.**

**but Old build getting deployed when you run the pipeline**

Comment: the `apache ant` tool is required to build java bindings

Comment: can i add in docker file with the RUN command